# How to make a QEvent that bubbles up to parent QObjects?

Tags: qt, qevent

I need to make a GUI button that tells it's parent (or *parent's parent* or even *parent's parent's parent*...) that different widget in the `QStackedLayout` should be shown. I created a custom QEvent:

```
class SwitchScreenEventWidget : public QEvent {
public:
  SwitchScreenEventWidget(QWidget* w) : SwitchScreenEvent(), widget(w) {
    if(widget==nullptr)
      throw "SwitchScreenEventWidget received null widget.";
  }
  virtual QWidget* getWidget() const {;return widget;}
private:
  QWidget* const widget;
};
```

I invoke it like this:

```
// Through debugger I checked that this is getting called properly
void GraphButton::buttonClicked()
{
  if(qApp!=nullptr && parent()!=nullptr)
    qApp->notify(parent(), new SwitchScreenEventWidget(getGraph()));
}
```

And handle it like this:

```
bool ViewStack::eventFilter(QEvent* e)
{
    if(e->type()>=QEvent::User) {
      if(SwitchScreenEvent* event = dynamic_cast<SwitchScreenEvent*>(e)) {
        // Show the given widget
      }
      return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

I use `eventFilter` which is then registered to the main app widget. But the event is not getting captured. Somewhere I read some `QEvent`s simply don't bubble up through the hierarchy.

So do all events bubble or not? If not, which do, which don't and why? And how do I make my event bubble properly?

Comment: Try setting the `accepted` flag of your event to false.

Comment: Why don't you use signal-slot system for this purpose? Are you limited somehow?

Comment: @troyane I don't want to directly access main widget from the `QPushButton` - I want the solution to be working regardless of the number of parent nodes the button has.

Comment: You could still use signal, just search recursivly for your ``findChildren<GraphButton*>`` from your most upper window and connect the signal.

Comment: @SebastianLange yeah, that's smart and I already do it for other things, but I would still prefer the event method, because those buttons can be added after app init.

Comment: @TomášZato Another option would be to have a MainWindow-Singleton or subclass Q[Gui]Application and have a signal-to-signal connection there, which then connects to your upper-widget slot (both probably bad design).

Comment: Can you provide maximum simplified but workin example, so we can play with it.

Comment: @troyane Ok, I will try to create a sample project. But the question itself is complicated enough - the code will be probably too large for a SO question.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way for you is subclassing `QApplication`, override `notify` method and do your "bubbles events" by yourself. I'm pretty sure that mouse and keyboard events "bubbles up" by this method and other events don't.

> bool QCoreApplication::notify(QObject * receiver, QEvent * event)
>
> Sends event to receiver: receiver->event(event). Returns the value
>   that is returned from the receiver's event handler. Note that this
>   function is called for all events sent to any object in any thread.
>
> For certain types of events (e.g. mouse and key events), the event
>   will be propagated to the receiver's parent and so on up to the
>   top-level object if the receiver is not interested in the event (i.e.,
>   it returns false).

So you can change this behavior by your realisation.

Also about you code example. I think this check

```
if( qApp!=nullptr )
```

is useless beacause of you always will have instance of qApp.